# Failed getting dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10, 64bit

Tags: boot

I'm very new to Linux and Ubuntu so I'm not very technical able in Ubuntu.

I have Windows 7 already installed. For a few weeks I booted Ubuntu 12.10, 64bit with a LiveUSB. I was able to save items with persistent memory.  The LiveUSB and persistent memory worked well.

From the LifeUSB I did a dual boot install. I step through the default settings and I did not do anything very technical.

I have a USB 2.0 hard disk drive connected to a USB 2.0 port. By default the space partitioning and install went to the USB HDD and not to my PC's drive.  The default install chose this external USB 2.0 drive.

Windows 7 is able to recognize it's part of the USB HDD when I'm in Windows 7 and doesn't see Ubuntu's partition which seem correct.

Here is the problem. When I boot my PC, there is no automatic choice on what OS to boot up in. So I boot into my BIOS and choose what appears to be the USB HDD (it's a odd name). I get a choice to boot in Ubuntu, Ubuntu Safe Mode, and a few others. When I boot into Ubuntu I get a blank screen for a long time. Then I get some error text messages. I'm not sure why this is happening, but IMHO it appears that the Ubuntu boot up can not see the USB HDD. Here are some of the error messages:

"Gave up waiting for root drive
Boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
-check roog delay= (did the system wait long enough)
-check root= (did the syttem wait for the right device).

By default, my PC automatically boots in Windows 7 ok.  But I can't get Ubuntu to boot.

Any suggestions? Ideas? Fixes? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ this will help in theory, its a nice util, but its not a magic bullet, but it will write to the MBR which is what your missing (thats what gives you the options when you boot right after the POST)